# Как записывать с камеры (по ip) с помощью jQuery (javascript)?

Tags: jquery, javascript, web-camera, видео

Можно ли осуществить запись с камеры (по ip) с помощью jQuery (javascript)? Или есть другие способы?

UPD : [[@vv2cc](/users/7163/vv2cc)](/users/7163/vv2cc), благодарю за ответ, не могу все еще привыкнуть фичам html 5 ))).
Как я понял, это способ онлайн трансляций видеопотока через веб камеры ноутбука ?
У меня задача такая : есть несколько ip камеры, и с них нужно осуществить запись, то есть сохранить файл на стороне сервера. Это осуществимо через javascript? Просто было бы лучше это все выполнялось на стороне сервера. 
Спасибо за ответы, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать использовать что-то подобное [Медиа сервер Erlyvideo и трансляция видео с IP-камеры в сеть Интернет ][1].


  [1]: http://itmultimedia.ru/media-server-erlyvideo-i-translyaciya-video-s-ip-kamery-v-set-internet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например с использованием html5, но не во всех браузерах. [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Тестил в хроме, последней версии - работает.

Comment: ого, интересная штука, спасибо.